# How to access ng-model values outside of ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have a table that is filled with `<input>` fields in every `<td>`, that are repeating in `ng-repeat`. In some cases some of the inputs may came with `null` value. I want to access the `ng-model` value, to detect when the user changes the value of `ng-model` in `!=null` to enable a button to process data in server. 
That is the code in `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in resultValue=(vm.ExcelDataDialog) | filter: FilterNullData" class="fade">
        <td style="min-width: 2px !important;width:2px !important">{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" ng-model="data.Pershkrimi" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.Pershkrimi != null, input_red: data.Pershkrimi == null}" />
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" ng-model="data.Klienti" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.Klienti != null, input_red: data.Klienti == null}" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.KodiArtikullit" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.KodiArtikullit != null, input_red: data.KodiArtikullit == null}" />
         </td>
         <td>
         <input type="number" ng-model="data.Sasia" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.Sasia != null, input_red: data.Sasia == null}" />
         </td>
         <td>
         <input type="number" ng-model="data.Cmimi" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.Cmimi != null, input_red: data.Cmimi == null}" />
         </td>
          <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.DateFillimi" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.DateFillimi != null, input_red: data.DateFillimi == null}" />
          </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" ng-model="data.DateMbarimi" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.DateMbarimi != null, input_red: data.DateMbarimi == null}" />
           </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I check if data are null in controller, but I want to check when they are filed   in the view to enable the button.
There is the button code:

```
 <md-button type="submit" id="create_offer"
            ng-click="vm.AddOfferByImportingExcel()"
            class="send-button md-accent md-raised"
            aria-label="krijo_oferte" 
            ng-disabled = "data.Pershkrimi == null">
   Krijo ofertë
 </md-button>
```

Comment: How have you used the reference of `ng-controller` in your code? Can you provide that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to validate your inputs and disable the button if any value is null / empty is to add angular form validation.   All you need to do is surround your code with a form (if not already done) and make sure it has a `name`.   Then add `ng-required="true"` to each of your inputs you want required.  Then you can access `formName.$invalid` to determine if the form is valid or not.

```
<form name="formName">

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in resultValue=(vm.ExcelDataDialog) | filter: FilterNullData" class="fade">
            <td style="min-width: 2px !important;width:2px !important">{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="data.Pershkrimi" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-required="true" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.Pershkrimi != null, input_red: data.Pershkrimi == null}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="data.Klienti" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-required="true" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.Klienti != null, input_red: data.Klienti == null}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="data.KodiArtikullit" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-required="true" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.KodiArtikullit != null, input_red: data.KodiArtikullit == null}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" ng-model="data.Sasia" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-required="true" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.Sasia != null, input_red: data.Sasia == null}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" ng-model="data.Cmimi" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-required="true" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.Cmimi != null, input_red: data.Cmimi == null}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="data.DateFillimi" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-required="true" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.DateFillimi != null, input_red: data.DateFillimi == null}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="data.DateMbarimi" ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }" ng-required="true" ng-class="{validate_for_creating_new_ofer: data.DateMbarimi != null, input_red: data.DateMbarimi == null}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <md-button type="submit" id="create_offer"
        ng-click="vm.AddOfferByImportingExcel()"
        class="send-button md-accent md-raised"
        aria-label="krijo_oferte" 
        ng-disabled = "formName.$invalid">
        Krijo ofertë
    </md-button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thats how I deal with it

Answer (score 0):

Could be a scope issue. Without seeing how the controller is defined and how the directive is used inside the template, it's hard to tell exactly the issue. If you're using ng-repeat, it will isolate the scope to whatever it's being looped over.

```
ng-repeat='data in datas'
```

will only make data available in the context of that element/directive. If you need other variables available, you need

```
ng-repeat='data in datas' other-variable='anotherVarYouNeed'
```